# Hierarchical tree view

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, hierarchical

I want to create a hierarchical from my MySql data response, it has jsut id and sponsor_id. I am not sure how to start, please help me solving this

`[ { "id": 2723021, "sponsor_id": "2723020" }, { "id": 2723022, "sponsor_id": "2723021" }, { "id": 2723023, "sponsor_id": "2723021" }, { "id": 2723024, "sponsor_id": "2723021" }, { "id": 2723025, "sponsor_id": "2723022" }, { "id": 2723026, "sponsor_id": "2723022" }, { "id": 2723027, "sponsor_id": "2723022" }, { "id": 2723028, "sponsor_id": "2723023" }, { "id": 2723029, "sponsor_id": "2723023" }, { "id": 2723030, "sponsor_id": "2723023" }, { "id": 2723031, "sponsor_id": "2723024" }, { "id": 2723032, "sponsor_id": "2723024" }, { "id": 2723033, "sponsor_id": "2723024" }, { "id": 2723034, "sponsor_id": "2723025" } ]`

[I want to make it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tog1v.jpg)

Nothing coming in my mind what & how to start

Comment: So you've tried nothing and you're all out of ideas? Your desired result has a an arbitrary root with arbitrary branching, and your question does nothing to explain how you want to map the source data to the desired result. Should the `id` be the root? Or the `sponsor_id`? Or is the sponsor_id mapped to the id? Or vice versa? Or do you want separate trees for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a map by item id, and find parents and add children to them, if no parent is found it's the root item.

```js
const arr = [ { "id": 2723021, "sponsor_id": "2723020" }, { "id": 2723022, "sponsor_id": "2723021" }, { "id": 2723023, "sponsor_id": "2723021" }, { "id": 2723024, "sponsor_id": "2723021" }, { "id": 2723025, "sponsor_id": "2723022" }, { "id": 2723026, "sponsor_id": "2723022" }, { "id": 2723027, "sponsor_id": "2723022" }, { "id": 2723028, "sponsor_id": "2723023" }, { "id": 2723029, "sponsor_id": "2723023" }, { "id": 2723030, "sponsor_id": "2723023" }, { "id": 2723031, "sponsor_id": "2723024" }, { "id": 2723032, "sponsor_id": "2723024" }, { "id": 2723033, "sponsor_id": "2723024" }, { "id": 2723034, "sponsor_id": "2723025" } ]


const map = arr.reduce((r, item) => (r[item.id] = item, r), {});
let root;
Object.values(map).forEach(item => {
  const parent = map[item.sponsor_id];
  parent ? (parent.children ??= []).push(item) : root = item;
});

console.log(root);
```

A simpler version:

```js
const arr = [ { "id": 2723021, "sponsor_id": "2723020" }, { "id": 2723022, "sponsor_id": "2723021" }, { "id": 2723023, "sponsor_id": "2723021" }, { "id": 2723024, "sponsor_id": "2723021" }, { "id": 2723025, "sponsor_id": "2723022" }, { "id": 2723026, "sponsor_id": "2723022" }, { "id": 2723027, "sponsor_id": "2723022" }, { "id": 2723028, "sponsor_id": "2723023" }, { "id": 2723029, "sponsor_id": "2723023" }, { "id": 2723030, "sponsor_id": "2723023" }, { "id": 2723031, "sponsor_id": "2723024" }, { "id": 2723032, "sponsor_id": "2723024" }, { "id": 2723033, "sponsor_id": "2723024" }, { "id": 2723034, "sponsor_id": "2723025" } ]


const map = {};
for(const item of arr) map[item.id] = item;
let root;
for(const id in map){
  const item = map[id];
  const parent = map[item.sponsor_id];
  if(parent){
    if(!parent.children) parent.children = [];
    parent.children.push(item);
  }else{
    root = item;
  }
}

console.log(root);
```

Comment: and what if i want to retrieve tree from a specific root id like from id 2723022 ?

Comment: @AbdulRazique `map[2723022]`